# Having to click button twice to trigger postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some validation code in my searchbutton click event and have been having problems with it having to be clicked twice to work. 
Asp Code:

```
        <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="148px" OnClick="SearchButton_Click"  style="height: 35px" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string title = TitleSearch.Text;
        Regex rgx = new Regex("^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$");
        if (title != "" && !rgx.IsMatch(title))
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Special characters are not allowed";
        }
        else
        {
             SearchButton.PostBackUrl = "results.aspx";

        }
}
```

Comment: Button's trigger `PostBacks` in aspx pages.. can you show what your `Page_Load` code looks like in the .cs file..? also use this `Response.Redirect("results.aspx");` instead of `SearchButton.PostBackUrl="resuts.aspx";`

Comment: @MethodMan is right. The first time you click the button, the button's `PostBackUrl` value is set. The second time it is clicked, the value can be used. Therefore, please try the `Response.Redirect` as suggested.

Comment: Problem there is that it doesn't seem to post any data to the next page.  What I really want it to do is to only postback if the regex validates

Comment: what do you mean `Problem there is that it doesn't seem to post any data to the next page` Please explain what you are trying to do and your understanding of the term `PostBack`

Comment: Alright, I should probably go from square one here.  The whole point of this is that i'm trying to prevent special characters from being entered into a textbox using regex and if it's valid, i'm trying to post the data on the page to a results page.  I decided to do validation on the button control, which seems to be a mistake since response.redirect seem to post data to the next page.

Comment: does the textbox have postback ? becaus if you change the text in the textbox it will do postback when you leave the textbox.so if you click the button the postback of the textbox fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the textbox have postback ? becaus if you change the text in the textbox it will do postback when you leave the textbox.so if you click the button the postback of the textbox fires.

I would check the textbox with java

Add in you page load event "Change EditGroup to the TextBoxName you want to check"

```
EditGroup.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return SomeTextChanged();");
```

This will add an onchange event to the textbox  and it will call the java function in your aspx page when you click the button

Then in your aspx page you add "Again change EditGroup to the name of the TextBox you want to check"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SomeTextChanged() {
    var Entered = document.getElementById('<%= EditGroup.ClientID %>');
    if (Entered.value != "" && !Entered.value.match("^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$"))
    {
        alert("Special characters are not allowed");
        document.getElementById('<%= EditGroup.ClientID %>').value = '';
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
</script>
```

So if you enter something that is not allowed you will get a message saying "Special characters are not allowed"
This will also stop you page from executing the rest of the code in the button click event.
And you also need to empty the textbox"i know this is maybe not the best way but if you don't empty the textbox and the user will click the button again it will not run the java code because the text didn't change"

So if if the text is good the java script will do nothing and the button click event will fire